# Overlay mask to the next time point in Simple ITK

Tags: python, simpleitk, image-registration

We are working on a problem of lesion tracking. So we have 3-d series of dicom images for two time points. Lesions are marked on time point - 1, using this we want to project the same lesions to the time point 2.

Currently we are following the approach below:

- Register 3-d series of images from timepoint-1(moving_image) with 3-d series of images from timepoint-2(fixed_image).
- Use the transform from the above registration to resample the masks on timepoint-1 with fixed image on timepoint-2 ==== This gives fixed_mask on time point 2.
- Overlay this fixed_mask to fixed_image to get the lesions on the timepoint-2.

Doing the above gives all blank images as the mask is mostly filled with null except that one tiny point.

Am I following the right approach? Is there any other way to overlay the mask from one time point to the next?

Comment: What interpolation are you using when resampling?  With a linear interpolation on a binary mask, you're mostly going to get zeros.  Try nearest neighbor interpolation.

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks for your response. I initially tried it with linear interpolator but then I also tried nearestneighbor after seeing your comment but it doesn't seem to work. It still returns null images.

Comment: can you share a sample image?